# Неконтролируемый сдвиг cardview в recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview, kotlin, gridlayoutmanager

При генерации карточек с пользователями они выглядят так (на данный момент я специально так оставил, для наглядности) (проблема сохраняется и на реальных девайсах)
[image: старт]
Но после первого же скролла вниз все карточки раздвигаются.
[image: после скролла]
И так происходит каждый раз, когда перехожу на данное активити. Как убрать "прыгание"?

```
class ListUserActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var recycleView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_user)

        recycleView = findViewById(R.id.user_recycle_view)
        val columns = calculateNoOfColumns(this)
        recycleView.let {
            it.setHasFixedSize(true)
            it.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, columns)
            it.adapter = UserAdapter(UserFactory.createList(30))
            it.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
            it.addItemDecoration(UserAdapter.SpacesItemDecoration(20))
        }
    }
}

fun calculateNoOfColumns(context: Context): Int {
    val displayMetrics = context.resources.displayMetrics
    val dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density
    return (dpWidth / 350).toInt()
}
```

Адаптер

```
class UserAdapter (private var users: ArrayList<User>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.UserViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.user_card_view, parent, false)
        return UserViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return users.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        holder?.let {
            it.bind(users[position])
            it.delete.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                users.removeAt(position)
                notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, 1)
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, itemCount)
        })
        }
    }

    class UserViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var userId = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.user_card_id)
        var userFio = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.user_card_fio)
        val edit = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.user_card_replace_button)
        val delete = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.user_card_delete_button)
        lateinit var user: User

        fun bind(user: User) {
            this.user = user
            userFio.text = user.firstName + " " + user.lastName
            userId.text = "id = ${user.id}"
        }
    }

    class SpacesItemDecoration(private val space: Int) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
        override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect?, view: View?, parent: RecyclerView?, state: RecyclerView.State?) {
            outRect?.apply {
                bottom = space
                top = space
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XML-код RecyclerView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/user_recycle_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

XML карточки

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/user_card_view"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:fadingEdge="none">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_card_avatar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_card_fio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Иванов Иван Иванович"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/user_card_avatar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_card_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_card_fio"
            tools:text="id=1202323283" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/user_card_replace_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:onClick="onClickEditUser"
            android:text="@string/edit"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/user_card_delete_button"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.29"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/user_card_avatar" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/user_card_delete_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:text="@string/delete"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Замените в XML карточки:

```
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="120dp"
```

на:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="120dp"
```

2) в функции `calculateNoOfColumns` захардкодьте временно значение 2.
Вы там используете значение 350, а в xml 320dp, судя по всему вы хотели добавить горизонтальные отступы между ячеек в 30dp.

3) Убедитесь что 350 не нужно перевести в dp.

4) Если вам нужны горизонтальные отступы - добавьте эту логику в `SpacesItemDecoration`

Comment: Действительно, оказалось что нужно было сделать в карточке максимальную ширину. Спасибо!